# Find the position over time of a point pushed against a circle

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry, vectors, circles

I'm trying to figure out the necessary math for determining the position of a particle with a given velocity when it encounters a circle at any angle. The idea is that the particle should move along the perimeter of the circle until it can resume course along its original vector (albeit offset by having to go around the circle's perimeter).

In my 2-d cartesian world, I know the position and radius of the circle. I know the velocity and direction of particle. I can determine if and where the particle will intersect with the circle, though I use two different methods for both. The rest of the problem is what I cannot figure out.

I feel like this shouldn't be too hard, but I have only a high school knowledge of physics and trigonometry and virtually no calculus. I'm also having difficulty searching for an answer on the internet which is why I'm trying here.

I appreciate any insight given.

For context, I'm trying to code the solution and have [asked this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74031101/how-do-i-figure-out-the-path-along-a-circle-when-a-velocity-vector-encounters-it).

[image: Example picture]
[image: Example picture]

Comment: If you look at the radius vector at the point where you lose contact with the circle, it is perpendicular to the direction of motion. So if the travel direction is $(v_x, v_y)$, the radius vector is in the direction $(-v_y, v_x)$ - you will need to scale it to the correct length, and maybe change its direction, depending on which side of the circles center the path passes. So if you need position at time $t$, you will need to break it into three parts: before, during, and after touching the circle, but once you know the "leaving contact" position it should just be a bunch of algebra.

Comment: How fast is the particle moving once it is moving along the circumference of the circle? If you know that then this is simple because $v=r\dot\theta$. From the angular velocity and time you get the exit point $p_1$ on the circle and your trajectory changes from $p_0+vt$ to $p_1+vt$.

Comment: "How fast is the particle moving once it is moving along the circumference of the circle?" This is something I may not know how to answer. I want to say the same thing that happens normally in the real world and from there eliminate friction. Like what happens if the wind is blowing a spec of dust across a sphere?

Comment: @jpwrunyan In the real world the particle would bounce off. It wouldn't ride the circle and continue along its original trajectory.

Comment: @JohnDouma - The best I can understand the description, this is for incredibly low Reynold's number, or think of an ant trying to walk in a specified direction, but having to go around a can of beans. That's the only way I can understand hugging the sides of the circle. In which case I'd expect the speed to be unchanged.

Comment: @jpwrunyan Then my instructions above should work fine. Divide the speed by the radius to get radians per second. Multiply that by the time to get the total angle of displacement along the circle in radians. From that, compute the new point and the new trajectory.

Comment: Thanks guys, I can't mark this as answered unless someone posts an answer, but intuitively, the explanation above makes sense.